# Call to a member function saveXML() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to use php to get data from my SQL Server database, in order to populate e XML document. But I have this error:  `Call to a member function saveXML() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\1mod.php on line 67` 
Can anyone help me please? What can I do?

This is my php  file

```
 <?php

    $file = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/result.xml","w");

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $server = "USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
    $options = array("UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"", "Database"=>"RESTORANTET");

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
    if(!$conn)
    {
    echo mysql_error();
    }   

    $Query = "SELECT MAX(ID_Rest) AS MAXID FROM RESTORANTET";   
    $Result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$Query)
    or die("Query to get blah failed with error111: ".mysql_error());
    $Row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    $nbPhase = $Row['MAXID']; 
    print "<TrafficPhase>";
    $i = 1;
    $k = 1;
    while ($i <= $nbPhase)
    {
        print "<Phase>\n";

        $Query1 = "SELECT * FROM RESTORANTET WHERE ID_Rest = $i"; 
        $Result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$Query1) or die("Query to get blah failed with error222: ".mysql_error());
        $Row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $Result1);


        print "<Option_id>" .$k. "</Option_id>\n";  
        print "<name>" .$Row1['Emri_Rest']. "</name>\n";
        print "<Option_Concept_ID>" .$Row1['Lloji_i_ushqimit']. "</Option_Concept_ID>\n";


        $i = $i + 1;
        print "</Phase>\n";
    }
    print "</TrafficPhase>\n";


    echo $file->saveXML();
    fwrite($file, $xml->w);
    fclose($file);


    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the $file object anywhere in this code.  That's probably the cause of your error.  See here for documentation to use the saveXML function: https://www.php.net/domdocument.saveXML

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse saveXML is function from DOMDocument Object

```
http://pl1.php.net/domdocument.saveXML
```

stream fopen doesnt support saveXML function. If you want use it you shuold create first object of DOMDocument for example:

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');

 echo $dom->saveXML(); /* <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> */
```

also if you want operate on xml element as string you can use

```
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('http://example.org/document.xml', NULL, TRUE);
    echo $sxe->asXML();
```